# naming duplicate drop downs

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have this inside my `<table>` in jsp. Whenever the add (+) button is clicked, new set of number field and drop down is displayed. I am wondering how can i access the new set of number field and drop down in my servlet. Considering that I can access the first set of number field and drop down given its `name="productquantity"` and `name="productline"` by `request.getParameter("productline")` in my servlet.

HTML:

```
<td>
    <div id="inline">
        <p id="addFields">
            <input type="number" required name="productquantity" min="1" max="99">
            <select name="productline" id="materials">
                <option value="CCTV Cameras">CCTV Cameras</option>
                <option value="FDAS">FDAS</option>
                <option value="Fire Extinguishers">Fire Extinguishers</option>
                <option value="Fire Pumps">Fire Pumps</option>
            </select>
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
</td>
<td valign="top">
    <button type="button" onclick="addFields();">+</button>
</td>
```

Javascript:

```
function addFields() {
    document.getElementById('addFields').innerHTML += '<input type="number" min="1" max="99">';
    var select = document.getElementById('materials').cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('addFields').appendChild(select);
    document.getElementById('addFields').innerHTML += "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I am not a jsp guy .. but what are the selectors available in jsp to select a dropdown .. since you are cloning a select the ids are all same , if its possible to access the dropdowns by class try adding a class property to the new dropdowns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously when you add a field, give it a new name.

```
 var nameAndID = "whatever_" + counter;
 element.innerHTML += "<input name='"+nameAndID+"' id='"+nameAndID+" />";
 counter = counter + 1;
```

In your servlet use request.getParameterNames to get a list of all parameter names and loop through it.